# Spring,Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, jsp, post

First of all say apology to ask this repeated Question..

Actually in my spring Application i have `user.jsp` and `professional.jsp`

here is my User.jsp:

```
  <form:form action="profile/user" modelAttribute="profile">
    <div>
        <jsp:include page="professional.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </div>

</form:form>
```

And here is my professional.jsp:

```
   <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<fieldset id="profile_proffiesional">
    <form:form action="profile/proffiesional" modelAttribute="PROFESSIONAL" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label for="position">Position</label>
            <form:input path="position" tabindex="4" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="location">Location</label>
            <form:input path="location" tabindex="5" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <form:input path="description" tabindex="5" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </p>
    </form:form>
</fieldset>
```

And here is my Controller class:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "profile")
public class UserProfileController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SessionData sessionData;

    @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String user(Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("PROFESSIONAL", new UserProfessionalForm());
        model.addAttribute("EDUCATIONAL", new UserEducationalForm());
        model.addAttribute("AWARDS", new UserAwardsForm());
        return "profile/user";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "proffessional", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String forgotPassword(UserProfessionalForm professionalForm,
            BindingResult result, Model model) {

        UserProfileVO userProfileVO = new UserProfileVO();
        userProfileVO.setUser(sessionData.getUser());
        userService.saveUserProfile(userProfileVO);
        model.addAttribute("professional", professionalForm);
        return "Your Professional Details Updated";
    }
}
```

`Problem` is when we are Click `Add` button in `professional.jsp`, there is no response in server console but below warning message shown:

```
  29 Mar, 2013 1:03:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Why this Warning coming? i'm already specified method="POST"..

Please help..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your user.jsp:

```
 <form:form action="profile/proffesional" modelAttribute="PROFESSIONAL">
     ---
     ---
    </form:form>
```

In your controller class:

(make it as a meaning full method name..Hear i think you are insert record in DB.)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "proffessional", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String proffessionalDetails(
            @ModelAttribute UserProfessionalForm professionalForm,
            BindingResult result, Model model) {

        UserProfileVO userProfileVO = new UserProfileVO();

        userProfileVO.setUser(sessionData.getUser());
        userService.saveUserProfile(userProfileVO);
        model.addAttribute("PROFESSIONAL", professionalForm);

        return "Your Professional Details Updated";

    }
```

Answer (score 15):

I had csrf enabled in my sprint security xml file, so I just added one line in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

This way I was able to submit the form having the `model` attribute.

Comment: or I did can send with the get method for returning ModelAndView function.

Answer (score 9):

In Jsp:

```
action="profile/proffiesional"
```

In Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "proffessional", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Spelling MisMatch !

Comment: again this warning coming:29 Mar, 2013 1:37:32 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: I have done so many of these... I don't dare to tell. haha

Answer (score 4):

You are missimg `@ModelAttribute` annotation for `UserProfessionalForm professionalForm` parameter in `forgotPassword` method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "proffessional", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String forgotPassword(@ModelAttribute UserProfessionalForm professionalForm,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    UserProfileVO userProfileVO = new UserProfileVO();
    userProfileVO.setUser(sessionData.getUser());
    userService.saveUserProfile(userProfileVO);
    model.addAttribute("professional", professionalForm);
    return "Your Professional Details Updated";
}
```

Comment: again this warning coming:29 Mar, 2013 1:37:32 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "proffessional", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String forgotPassword(@ModelAttribute("PROFESSIONAL") UserProfessionalForm professionalForm,
            BindingResult result, Model model) {

        UserProfileVO userProfileVO = new UserProfileVO();
        userProfileVO.setUser(sessionData.getUser());
        userService.saveUserProfile(userProfileVO);
        model.addAttribute("professional", professionalForm);
        return "Your Professional Details Updated";
    }
```

Comment: No.. again that warning come but ..copy same code and doing Educational (above code i'm include EducationalForm in model attrebute)..So in that time working perfectly..but Professional not working

Comment: also put a slash in fromt of proffessional like this /proffessional

Answer (score 1):

For information i removed the action attribute and i got this error when i call an ajax post..Even though my action attribute in the form looks like this `action="javascript://;"`

I thought I had it from the ajax call and serializing the form but I added the dummy action attribute to the form back again and it worked.