# GET or POST request from AJAX call is not being handled

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, http

Am getting this error after calling AJAX request.
Control is hitting to server side and all process is working fine. But before calling controller code am getting this Error and stucked here itself.

**Jsp**

```
<form id="pop-up3reset">
..................
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="manualModePopupSave" />
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#manualModePopupSave').click(function() {
 var userno=$('#userno').val();
 var on_off1 = $('#pop-up3onoff1').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
 var search = {
 "user_no" : userno,
 "onoff1" : on_off1
 };

var myJsonStringsearch = JSON.stringify(search);
alert(myJsonStringsearch);
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "setManualModeForAjax",
contentType : "application/json",
async : true,
cache : false,
data : myJsonStringsearch,
dataType : 'json',
success : function(response) {
    $('#onoff1').val(response.onoff1);
if(response.errorMessage == "-1"){
    sweetAlert("not in communication", "","error");
}else if(response.errorMessage == "M,1"){
    sweetAlert("Request is Not Reachable", "","error");
}
},
});
});
});
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/setManualModeForAjax"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ManualModeFromAjax setManualMode(@RequestBody ManualModeFromAjax manualModeFromAjax)throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("In manual mode for AJAX request");
    ....................
    return manualModeFromAjax;
}
```

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
>   WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
>   WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported

**Network**

> Request URL:http://localhost:8080/PROJECT/login?
>
> Request Method:GET
>
> Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
>
> Remote Address:[::1]:8080

Please help

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699350/spring-request-method-post-not-supported

Comment: thank you for ur response.. I have tried it. My issue is with Ajax call only.

Comment: in the network it says `GET` ?

Comment: Yes.. In network it show GET and the same error in server side console too

Comment: I ran it on my console and the request was `POST` .

Comment: I have checked again. request is still GET only. I have added image u can check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your button is a `submit` one, not just a `button`. So that when you click the button the javascript method bound to the action is executed but you are not preventing the default action so the form is also sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded` and because, and I am just guessing, your controller is only ready to handled `form-urlencoded` requests is when you get the request method not supported error.

You have different options. You could:

- use `button` as type for your button instead of `submit`
- use [Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- just return false on your javascript method

You javascript should be something like:

```
$('#manualModePopupSave').click(function(e) {
    //Use this...
    e.preventDefault();

    var userno=$('#userno').val();

    ....

    //or this.
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This worked out.. But y will tht default be GET request..?

Comment: Neither your form tag nor your ajax call are defining a value for the method property. In both cases the default one is GET. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3 http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ You need to use method instead of type on the ajax call.

Comment: Okay i got it.. Thank you for ur explaination