# Http POST method not supported

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I was performing a CRUD operation, when tried to delete an item using POST method it gave an error `Request method 'POST' not supported`

Here is a form which performs delete :
adminLogin.jsp

```
<form:form method="delete" action="deleteMenuItems/${itemName}" modelAttribute="menuItems">
       Item name <input type="text" name="itemName"></br>
       <input type="submit" value="delete">
</form:form>
```

AdminPageController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteMenuItems/{itemName}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ModelAndView deleteMenuItem(@PathVariable("itemName") String itemName){
    this.menuItemsDao.deleteItems(itemName);
    return new ModelAndView("adminLogin");

}
```

MenuItemDao.java

```
public void deleteItems(String itemName) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    menuItems = (MenuItems) session.load(MenuItems.class, new String(itemName));
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(menuItems);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Also when I restart server everytime the previous vaule from db is cleaned and new table is formed, what might be the configuration in hibernate to solve this?

the problem might be simple but I am new to spring hope you will help me, thank you

Comment: `Request method 'POST' not supported` this is an error from the java console right??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PUT and DELETE methods in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629653/using-put-and-delete-methods-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: @KenrySanchez Yes that's the error in java console

Comment: is not better to change `RequestMethod.DELETE` to a POST method?? You're using DELETE, maybe it is badly implemented.

Comment: @KenrySanchez i have tried using get post nothing helped

Comment: Changing to Post and tell me what's the message console

Comment: DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing POST request for [/restroo/admin/deleteMenuItems/]
Looking up handler method for path /admin/deleteMenuItems/
Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
Request method 'POST' not supported
Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
Successfully completed request

This is the error @KenrySanchez

Comment: now with GET it is not giiving error  but the task to delete is not being performed i.e items are not being deleted

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="deleteMenuItems/{itemName}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)

Comment: Can you show what is inside of `ModelAndView`?

Comment: Sorry didn't get. What should I send model and view separately ?

Answer (score 0):

The current HTML5 draft does not support PUT or DELETE in forms. you have two options: 
1 . change the form to post and also your method in function in java
2. use ajax to send the form using delete method

Comment: changing that also didn't help giving the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699350/spring-request-method-post-not-supported, you have a nice example here, review the method in java and the sintax in your action.. seems there are two //