# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence, spring-rest

I have an entity TaskInfo that joins two entities Task and TaskDetail for dropdowns.

But when I try to persist TaskInfo entity I get "org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported" error.

When I remove joined entities from TaskInfo entity, persist works fine.

I try to CascadeType=DETACH for joined entities but it does not work, I still get the error.

What is wrong can you help me?

This is TaskInfo entity, I removed setter/getters.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TASKINFO")
public class TaskInfo implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer taskInfoId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="TASKID", nullable=false)
    private Integer taskId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="TASKDETAILID", nullable=false)
    private Integer taskDetailId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Task.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="taskId", referencedColumnName="taskId")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Task taskListDD;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=TaskDetail.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="taskDetailId", referencedColumnName="taskDetailId")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.DETACH})
    private TaskDetail taskDetailListDD;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newTaskInfo" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveTaskInfo(@Valid TaskInfo taskInfo, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registrationTaskInfo";
    }

    taskInfoService.save(taskInfo);
    //taskInfoDegreeService.save(taskInfoDegree);

    model.addAttribute("success", "TaskInfo " + taskInfo.getTaskInfoId() + " registered successfully");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());

    return "registrationsuccess";
}
```

Service part:

```
@Override
public void save(TaskInfo taskInfo)
{
    dao.save(taskInfo);
}
```

DAO part:

```
@Override
public void save(TaskInfo taskInfo)
{
    persist(taskInfo);
}
```

JSP part:

```
    <div class="well lead">Task Info Registration Form</div>
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="taskInfo" class="form-horizontal">
        <form:input type="hidden" path="taskInfoId" id="taskInfoId"/>
        <form:input type="hidden" path="taskId" id="taskId"/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="taskId">Task Id</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:select class="form-control" id="selectTaskListDD" path='taskListDD'> 
                        <option value="-1">-Select-</option> 
                        <form:options items="${taskListDD}"/>
                    </form:select>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="taskId" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $("#selectTaskListDD").change(function(){
                var taskId = $("#selectTaskListDD").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "/SpringMVCHibernateWithSpringSecurityExample/taskDetailListDD/" + taskId,
                    success: function(data){
                        var slctTaskDetailDD=$('#selectTaskDetailDD'), option="";
                        slctTaskDetailDD.empty();

                        option = option + "<option value='-1'>-Select-</option>";
                        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                            option = option + "<option value='"+data[i].taskDetailId + "'>"+data[i].taskDetailName + "</option>";
                        }
                        slctTaskDetailDD.append(option);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("error");
                    }

                });
                document.getElementById("taskId").value = taskId;
            });

        </script>

        <form:input type="hidden" path="taskDetailId" id="taskDetailId"/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="taskDetailId">Task Detail Id</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <%-- <form:input type="integer" path="taskDetailId" id="taskDetailId" class="form-control input-sm"/> --%>

                    <form:select class="form-control" id="selectTaskDetailDD" path="taskDetailListDD">
                       <option value="-1">-Select-</option> 
                    </form:select>

                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="taskDetailId" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        $("#selectTaskDetailDD").change(function(){
            var taskDetailId = $("#selectTaskDetailDD").val();
            document.getElementById("taskDetailId").value = taskDetailId;
        });
        </script>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-actions floatRight">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${edit}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/> or <a href="<c:url value='/listTaskInfo' />">Cancel</a>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/> or <a href="<c:url value='/listTaskInfo' />">Cancel</a>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: I have added controller, service and dao parts.

Comment: is your taskInfoService class annotaded with @Service ?

Comment: Yes, it is annotated like 
@Service("taskInfoService")
@Transactional

Comment: try removing @Transactional

Comment: I tried but get the same error

Comment: Well it's hard to find the cause based on the code you provided but try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699350/spring-request-method-post-not-supported

Comment: This error basically occurs if the request parameters from front end and back miss matched. Can you check both side?

Comment: I have check many times Ramesh but I am still missing something. I have also added the jsp part of the code.

Comment: Please add @RequestBody next to Valid  annotation in controller class and check

Comment: I have just tried Ponni but it did not work